# rsync 3.0.9 not duplicating directory attributes

Tags: rsync

I want to make an exact copy of a mounted filesystem to a clean destination. I am using the following options:

```
rsync -vaHAXE /src/* /dst/
```

however the destination ends up with a root structure where the directory access rights are all different, owner is different, hidden directories are omitted.

Source `ls`

```
drwxrwsr--.  4  owner  group ...
drwxrwxrwx.  6  owner  group ...
```

Destination `ls`

```
drwx--S---.  2  root   group ...
drwx--S---.  2  root   group ...
```

`-A` should preserve ACLs
`-a` implies `-o` which should preserve owner
`-E` should preserve execution rights

Note the change in link count is because I terminated the sync, it isn't part of the issue I believe.

Why is the command not yielding accurate results? Does `-a` and `-HAXE` conflict? How can I get an identical sync?